# Android String Not Equal

Tags: android, string, equals

I am brand new to Java and Android so I am sure this will be an easy question/answer. I know that to find out if a string is equal to another string you use the equal function. In my situation, I am scanning a QR Code where the result of the scan is Similar to "EMPLOYEE~~John Smith~~DIVISION~~Maintenance". I need to know how to do the following:

```
String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
// I know that "contents" contains the string " EMPLOYEE~~John Smith~~DIVISION~~Maintenance"

String[] myJunk = contents.split("~~");
// This should split everything up into an array named myJunk (right)?

String val1 = myJunk[0];
// Now val1 Should be equal to "EMPLOYEE"

if (myJunk[0].equals(val1)){
    // Do Something
}
```

In the example Java Code, myJunk[0] never equals val1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That has to be equal. I just tried out that code. You may have some other problem. Can you post the full code?

Comment: yeah, works for me to, tried it out and myJunk[0].equals(val1) == true

Answer (score 2):

i've tried this and it works , so try to display the contents variable ,  probably the problem is in the extras , try to display it in logCat :

```
String contents = "EMPLOYEE~~John Smith~~DIVISION~~Maintenance";
 String[] myJunk = contents.split("~~");
 // This should split everything up into an array named myJunk (right)?

 String val1 = myJunk[0];
 Toast.makeText(this, "val1 = "+val1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(this, "val2 = "+myJunk[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 // Now val1 Should be equal to "EMPLOYEE"

 if (myJunk[0].equals(val1)){
     Toast.makeText(this, "equals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: That's not the same as he posted. Notice the space in the string. And by the way that doesn't solve the problem which must be somewhere else since the code in question works.

Comment: @edem : you can just edit my answer to add the space , it's all , and i 've tested his code to verify it , and it works for me , because he is comparing the same values , 
and you dont need to unvote to -1 , we're here to help

Comment: I tested too but these are not answers, because they doesn't solve the problem. Either the question is faulty or the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: if it didn't solve the problem , so everytime some one who try to help you will unvote -1 ????

Answer (score 0):

Your string is:
`EMPLOYEE~~John Smith~~DIVISION~~Maintenance`

So after spliting, myJunk[0] will contain `EMPLOYEE` (notice the space in front of the word EMPLOYEE).

So before comparing , you will need to [trim](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) your value

Comment: doesn't make any sense to me. He does `String val1 = myJunk[0];` right before the comparison.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me either.

Comment: aha you are right, i havent notice that he is comparing the 2 same values.

Answer (score 0):

The method i usually use, is to print out my variables when in doubt. So if you are unsure of where the problem is, you could try something like this.
(It requires you to be able to see the output, in logcat for example)

```
String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); 
// I know that "contents" contains the string " EMPLOYEE~~John Smith~~DIVISION~~Maintenance"
System.out.println("contents is "+contents );

String[] myJunk = contents.split("~~"); 
// This should split everything up into an array named myJunk (right)?
System.out.println("Array size is "+myJunk.length);

String val1 = myJunk[0]; 
// Now val1 Should be equal to "EMPLOYEE"

for(int i=0; i < myJunk.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("String "+i+ "in array is: "+myJunk[i]);
}
//Here i run through the array and print every element.

if (myJunk[0].equals(val1)){     
// Do Something 
}
```

It is a bit overkill, but this is mostly to show one way of getting all the information you need to find the problem :)

Comment: You should use Log.d(YOUR_TAG, "your string") for debug logging and monitoring the process in logcat | grep YOUR_TAG in my opinion.